# Jest with imports and ES6 syntax

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app

We have an old version of an application done with create-react-app. This is using `react-scripts 1.1.5`.

I am trying to use Jest with react-testing-library.

When running the specs, I have the following issue:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /home/mgarcia/projects/v3bitex-implementation/node_modules/apex-web/lib/redux/middlewares/authMiddleware.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _regeneratorRuntime from 'babel-runtime/regenerator';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^
    
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Fine. It seems to be complaining about ES6 being used in a node module. So I run the script with the following:

`npm run test --  --transformIgnorePatterns "node_modules/apex-web"`

This seems to work, until I run into:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /home/mgarcia/projects/v3bitex-implementation/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/node_modules/pretty-format/build/plugins/DOMElement.js: Unexpected token, expected ( (25:10)
        23 |   try {
        24 |     return typeof val.hasAttribute === 'function' && val.hasAttribute('is');
      > 25 |   } catch {
           |           ^
        26 |     return false;
        27 |   }
```

So it seems I have to exclude another library.

Am I missing something here? Should I manually list every single library that has this issue? Is there a version of react-scripts that automatically handles this without any issues?

I have tried to upgrade to v2, but everything broke miserably.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error installing `@babel/preset-env` and creating the file `babel.config.js`, I also modified `jest.config.js`.

Try it:

- run in your root path terminal:

  ```
  npm i -D @babel/preset-env
  ```
- Create the file `babel.config.js` in the root path with this line:

  ```
  module.exports = {presets: ['@babel/preset-env']}
  ```